# Javascript: Create a form with a parametric number of textbox (TinyMCE)

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am not a Web developer, I have to do just a small task once, but I hate copy & paste.

Look at the code below, I'd like to avoid copy and paste (question1, question2 ,..., question[i]). I'd like to create a for statement but I should handle properties with a dynamic name. In c# I would use reflection or dynamic.

Is it possible in Javascript? Is it the correct approach? Should I dynamically generate the code and use Eval()?

```js
tinymce.PluginManager.add('test_containers', function(editor, url) {
  editor.addButton('test_containers2', {
    title: 'Container 2',
    text: 'Container 2',
    onclick: function() {
      editor.windowManager.open({
        title: 'Test Container',
        body: [{
          type: 'container',
          layout: 'stack',
          columns: 2,
          minWidth: 500,
          minHeight: 500,
          items: [{
            type: 'textbox',
            name: 'question1'
          }, {
            type: 'textbox',
            name: 'question2'
          }, ]
        }],
        onsubmit: function(e) {
          ed.insertContent(e.data.question1 + e.data.question2);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

tinymce.init({
  selector: '#mytextarea',
  plugins: 'colorpicker  test_containers',
  toolbar: 'test_containers2'
});

// Taken from core plugins
var editor = tinymce.activeEditor;

function createColorPickAction() {
  var colorPickerCallback = editor.settings.color_picker_callback;

  if (colorPickerCallback) {
    return function() {
      var self = this;

      colorPickerCallback.call(
        editor,
        function(value) {
          self.value(value).fire('change');
        },
        self.value()
      );
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="mytextarea">Hello, World!</textarea>
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/Revious/gm2phuva/3/

Comment: can you be more specific on your question? What do you mean by `I'd like to create a kind of for to handle question1, question2,..., question[i]`

Comment: @Thinker: yes, of course with pleasure, but I'm not a native english speaker... I think the word "handle" is confusing.. I don't want to copy and paste question1, question2. And there is only one way to achieve that in every development language: the for statement.

Comment: The problem is not writing a for in javascript, but handling properties with a dynamic name. In c# I would use reflection or dynamic. And in Javascript?

Comment: from my understanding, you want to add `items` dynamically?

Comment: @Thinker: yes, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you need to add the items dynamically.

I have added two function on your code.

`createArr` -> will create the array of list of the specified number (n)

`handleQuesData` -> will concat the data of all the questions and pass it to `onsubmit` function

```js
tinymce.PluginManager.add('test_containers', function(editor, url) {
 // item creation dynamically
  let createArr = (n) => {
    let arr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      arr.push({
        type: 'textbox',
        name: `question{i+1}`
      })
    }
    return arr;
  }
 // onsubmit handled dynamically
  let handleQuesData = (data, n) => {
    let quesdata = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      quesdata += data[`question{i+1}`]
    }
    return quesdata
  }
 
  let numItem = 2;
  editor.addButton('test_containers2', {
    title: 'Container 2',
    text: 'Container 2',
    onclick: function() {
      editor.windowManager.open({
        title: 'Test Container',
        body: [{
          type: 'container',
          layout: 'stack',
          columns: 2,
          minWidth: 500,
          minHeight: 500,
          items: createArr(numItem)
        }],
        onsubmit: function(e) {
          ed.insertContent(handleQuesData(e.data, numItem));
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

tinymce.init({
  selector: '#mytextarea',
  plugins: 'colorpicker  test_containers',
  toolbar: 'test_containers2'
});


// Taken from core plugins
var editor = tinymce.activeEditor;

function createColorPickAction() {
  var colorPickerCallback = editor.settings.color_picker_callback;

  if (colorPickerCallback) {
    return function() {
      var self = this;

      colorPickerCallback.call(
        editor,
        function(value) {
          self.value(value).fire('change');
        },
        self.value()
      );
    };
  }
}
```

Here is the demo code : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p769sn2L/2/)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can dynamically generate the list of items.

```js
tinymce.PluginManager.add('test_containers', function(editor, url) {

    const totalQuestions = 10;
    let questions = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < totalQuestions; i++) {
        questions.push({
            type: 'textbox',
            name: 'question' + i
        });
    }

    editor.addButton('test_containers2', {
        title: 'Container 2',
        text: 'Container 2',
        onclick: function() {
        editor.windowManager.open({
            title: 'Test Container',
            body: [{
                type: 'container',
                layout: 'stack',
                columns: 2,
                minWidth: 500,
                minHeight: 500,
                items: questions
            }],
            onsubmit: function(e) {
            ed.insertContent(e.data.question1 + e.data.question2);
            }
        });
        }});
    });

//......
```